# Optimizing SVG viewBox Animation in Firefox

Tags: javascript, performance, firefox, svg, snap.svg

I'm developing a javascript chart library, I chose **svg** for this purpose.
It's crucial to change viewBox time to time to allow users to see all parts of the chart.

I used `snap.svg` for animating my viewBox attribute and it's somehow smooth but not satisfying.

I wonder is there other techniques to improve svg re-rendering, like using GPU or something?

https://jsfiddle.net/omidh/uwc0y524/1/

Most sluggish when all viewBox Attributes are changed at once, anyway to improve this? My svg only contains `<line>` and `<circle>`

Edit: It's much more smooth in chrome than firefox, so chrome is fine.

Edit: Even Internet Explorer is better than firefox

Comment: Optimising for which version of which UA? Whatever we suggested might be obsolete or invalid with the next release of your UA.

Comment: I'd probably show the code you're using on a jsfiddle just to check you aren't doing something odd.

Comment: @RobertLongson Sorry I don't know what do you mean by saying UA, However I add some stuff to my original post

Comment: If you coded this in SMIL it would likely be smoother in Firefox.

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks I changed it to SMIL but firefox is sluggish, still. To comprehend the difference open my fiddle in both firefox and chrome then press "left" button on the top of the page first in firefox then in chrome. You can easily see the difference

Comment: I see no SMIL in your fiddle.

Comment: @RobertLongson https://jsfiddle.net/omidh/uwc0y524/6/ , It will move to left automatically after 3 seconds

Comment: @RobertLongson sorry, not true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not the Animation method but svg Render performance in Firefox.

Previously I used two `<line>` per "x" shape in my svg, So to reduce object counts I changed it to one `<polyline>` which gave me 10% - 20% rendering speed boost.